Designing a D-FF in Virtuoso to create 90 degrees phase shift
I am currently trying to design a digital circuit in Cadence to produce a 90 degrees phase shift to a CLK signal within my current circuit.
Below is an image of a D-FF setup as well as the output waveforms where "/net3" is the input CLK and "/net9" should be the 90 degrees phase shifted clock.



It doesn't seem to work at all, would anyone know why that is? Also is there any suggestion for any circuits that I could use to produce 90 degrees phase shift more on the digital side rather than the analog All pass filters.
Any guidance is much appreciated. Thanks!

look at the bottom timing diagram ... what is the relationship between the 0° term, the clock falling edge and the 90° term? ... what about the 90° term, the clock rising edge and the 0° term?

The timing diagram  makes sense to me , however when hooking up the circuit in a similar fashion it doesn't seem to produce the right outputs in simulation hence the concern.

The timing diagram makes sense to me ... which part does not make sense? ... your question should be about the timing diagram, not about flip-flops ... if you do not understand what the timing diagram is showing you, then how do you hope to design a circuit
